# Can't pass Request from controller to another controller's view

Tags: laravel, controller

I'm trying to pass a Request from a controller, but for reasons I don't understand the data simply isn't being passed through to the view and I get `Undefined variable: request`. I have confirmed that right up until the redirect to the action the request is populated with all the additional variables, so the issue must be after that.

**ManufacturerController**

```
public function decode(Manufacturer $manufacturer, Request $request) {

    $validated = $request->validate([
    "id" => ["required","min:5","max:30", "alpha_num"],
    "email" => ["email","required","max:255"]
    ]);

    $request->merge([
        "manufacturer" => $manufacturer
    ]);

    // Pass the Request to the Manufacturer model and return a modified version of it
    $request = $manufacturer->oneplus($request); 

    return redirect()->action([TransactionController::class, "index"])->with($request);
    }

abort(404);

}
```

**Manufacturer model:**

```
public function oneplus($request) {

  $id = $request->id;

  /* BUSINESS LOGIC THAT GENERATES $new FROM $id... */
  
  $request->merge([
    'new' => $new
  ]);
      
  return $request;
}
```

**Route in web.php**

```
Route::get('/payment', [TransactionController::class, "index"]);
```

**TransactionController:**

```
public function index()
{
    return view('payment');
}
```

**payment.blade.php**

```
{{ dd($request->new) }}
```

Comment: You need to access your [flashed session data](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) using `session('request')`.

Comment: @apokryfos I see, so the cause is with the redirect. Is there a way to do what I'm doing - while still being able to use `$request` directly in the view - without the redirect?

Comment: where are you calling ManufacturerController controller's decode function

Comment: @Deepak From a form on a different view, but it's irrelevant to this question because as mentioned the Request is correctly formed right up until the action redirect.

Comment: ok so two thing you can change here. 1->in TransactionController return request as data like `return view('payment', ['request' => $request->session()->get('request')]);` and change function name to `public function index(Request $request)`. 2nd->in ManufacturerController change `return redirect()->action([TransactionController::class, "index"])->with($request);` to `return redirect()->action([TransactionController::class, "index"])->with('request', $request->all());`

Comment: @apokryfos Since yours is currently the best/easiest answer it looks like I'll have to go with it and just make the necessary changes to my view. Please free to add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem when using redirects is that the redirect will cause a brand new request to happen. When using `redirect()->with('variable', 'value')` you need to then access that variable using:

```
session('variable')`
```

the reason being that the variable is "flashed" to the next request via the session (in practice it's not sent to the next request, it's just available for the next request through the session and then disappears).

While this may be an easy solution to your problem a better solution is to not use a redirect if possible. Here's a simplification of an alternative:

ManufacturerController:

```
public function decode(Manufacturer $manufacturer, Request $request) {

    $validated = $request->validate([
    "id" => ["required","min:5","max:30", "alpha_num"],
    "email" => ["email","required","max:255"]
    ]);

    $request->merge([
        "manufacturer" => $manufacturer
    ]);

    // Pass the Request to the Manufacturer model and return a modified version of it
    $request = $manufacturer->oneplus($request); 
    $transactionController = app()->make(TransactionController::class);
    return $transactionController->index($request);
}
```

TransactionController:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return view('payment')->with("request", $request);
}
```

This will call the other controller method within the same request.

Comment: Great solution, I don't fully understand it but I'm not complaining because getting rid of the redirect also solved a CSRF error I was getting with Stripe. There was something missing which I've now edited in, but with it the solution works perfectly.

Comment: I'm curious, is there a reason you believe this is a better solution to doing a redirect?

Comment: A redirect launches a whole new request and since you need to retain the current request in some way, a redirect is problematic. If you want to use a redirect you'd need a way to craft it in such a way to retain the current request parameters. If you have a `GET` request you can of course pass them as a query string but the query string has a stricter size limit that the body of a request. So the reason I believe this is a better solution is because the scenarios where a redirect is better would be very limited and it's harder to craft the redirect request correctly

Comment: Passing the request in the session could potentially work, though it's probably better if you instead passed `$request->all()` in the session (which is an array) instead of the session object which has information which you don't need and may end up having parts that are not serializable (making the code break in mysterious ways)

Comment: Coming back to this, the only disadvantage to this method that I've been able to find is that the URL remains the same, whereas on a "traditional" redirect the URL would change to reflect the new route. Any idea how/whether it's possible to also make the service container change to the new route's URL?

Comment: No this approach is meant to be used when you want to share common code among different URLs. If you want to change URL you will need a redirect in which case you will need to evaluate whether you need to pass the entire request through the session when you redirect or if there's a better solution for you to both go to a new URL and only (somehow) transfer the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make few changes in TransactionController and ManufacturerController to make it work

TransactionController:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return view('payment', [
        'request' => $request->session()->get('request')
     ]);
}
```

ManufacturerController:

```
public function decode(Manufacturer $manufacturer, Request $request) {

    $validated = $request->validate([
    "id" => ["required","min:5","max:30", "alpha_num"],
    "email" => ["email","required","max:255"]
    ]);

    $request->merge([
        "manufacturer" => $manufacturer
    ]);

    // Pass the Request to the Manufacturer model and return a modified version of it
    $request = $manufacturer->oneplus($request); 

    return redirect()->action([TransactionController::class, "index"])->with('request', $request->all());
    }

abort(404);

}
```

Comment: This partially solves the problem but has a similar problem to @apokryfos's solution which requires changing the view - the returned Request is no longer an object so I get the error `Trying to get property 'new' of non-object`. Is there an equivalent command that I can use to replace `redirect->action([])` that still allows me to access the array as an object in the view?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass like this 
ManufacturerController :

```php
return redirect()->action(
    [TransactionController::class, "index"],
    ['data' => $request]
);
```

Route in web.php

```php
// ? = Optional
Route::get('/payment/{data?}', [TransactionController::class, "index"]);
```

TransactionController:

```php
public function index($data)
{
    return view('payment');
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question but I would rather keep this form data out of the URL for security purposes, although upvoted anyway because if not for this requirement it would be a very good solution.